# Iterate Through Rows of CSV File and Assign Particular Row Value to Package Variable

Tags: sql-server-2008, ssis

I am currently using SSIS 2008 and am fairly new to it. I have a programming background with some Java, VBA, and VB.NET.

I have a connection to a csv file that contains a list of URLs.
There about a thousand rows in the file and with each row, I want to add the URL to a package variable that will be used to see if the most current link has already been downloaded and updated or not.

I've set up a Foreach Loop Container that is intended to loop through each row of of the csv file.

However, I cannot figure out how to "look at" each row.  Once I can do that I know it will be no problem to assign the URL to the variable but I am stuck mid-way.  Does anyone have any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

You want to *do* something to each row from a given source. That's usually a data flow type of activity. Drop a `Data Flow Task` onto your Control Flow. Inside that data flow, add a Flat File Source. In the Flat file connection manager, click New and fill out the details for your file. I assume it's just one data element (url) per line. Click OKs and then you should have a working data source.

Great, now all you need to do is that "something" to the data coming in which in your case is "see if the most current link has already been downloaded and updated or not." I'm not sure exactly *what* that translates to but whatever you attach (look up task, script task, etc) to the output from the Flat File Source will perform that operation for every row flowing through it.

Comment: Thank you for your response billinkc, I really appreciate it.  I will give your suggestions a go and get back to you.